# How to define the union of closed subschemes in an affine scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to define the union of closed subschemes in an affine scheme?
Suppose $I$ and $J$ define closed subschemes of $\operatorname{Spec}R$, how should we define their intersection?

Eisenbud and Harris (GTM 197, p24) defined it by  $I\cap J$ and used it to derive the "double points"(p60). We can also define it by $IJ$, which has the same underluing space.

Which one is more useful and why?

Comment: I assume "Jarris" is meant to be "Harris". (I would fix it, but the silly lower bound on edits won't let me.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My default choice would for the scheme-theoretic union would be $I\cap J$.

There is a natural injection $R/I\cap J \to R/I \times R/J$, which you can
interpret as saying that Spec $R/I\cap J$ is the scheme-theoretic image
of the natural map from Spec $R/I \coprod $ Spec $R/J$, and this scheme-theoretic image is a natural choice for what you would call the scheme-theoretic union of the two closed subschemes.

Also, one would expect union to be idempotent, i.e. the union of Spec $R/I$ with itself should just be Spec $R/I$ again.

Considering Spec $R/IJ$ can also have its uses (especially if $I = J$), but 
I wouldn't call it a *union*.

Comment: Also, one would like to have that to write a variety as the union of its irreducible component is the same as to find the primary decomposition of the associated ideal.